# How can I add a column to the return of a criteria?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria

in sql I can do it

```
select Id,Teste=1 from MovimentacoesDocECF
```

and the return of research adds a column "Test" with the value 1 for all records ...

how can I do this on a criteria in nhibernate in C # ...

I need to do this with an enum ... I would do something like `select Id,Teste="Name_Um" from MovimentacoesDocECF"` where the value of "Teste" is an enum

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem ... using the method

```
criteria.SetProjection(
                        Projections.ProjectionList()
                                    .Add(Projections.Constant (MeuEnum.Name_Um), 
                        "Test"
                      )
```